# I want to make scheduled chat with laravel - Cron task

Tags: php, laravel, cron

There is an Api called `sendMessage` and the uri is `chat/sendMessage` and the body of this uri is :

```
{
   'Message': " Hello ",
   'targetUser: "SomeOne"
}
```

so what the code does after calling this uri it goes to `MessageController` and use the `Send()` function and will send the message to the `targetUser`, But What I want to do is to make this to **Scheduled Chat** , meaning that I want to Change the Body of uri to This :

```
{
    'Message': " Hello ",
    'targetUser: "SomeOne",
    'Date' : " 4 5 30 3 6"  // which means : 04:05 on 30/march on Saturday.This is Cron type date in laravel
}
```

and After calling the uri this will do the job on that Date for me.

So I created the `ChatCron.php` file in `App/Console/Command` Directory then I have to handle the function in `handle()` and then Call it from `Kernel.php`.

**The problem is :**

1. I actually can't figure it out how to Connect `ChatCron.php` to `MessageController` .
2. I don't know how to tell Laravel that : After calling the `uri` go to `ChatCron.php` and set the timer for calling the `Send()` function in `MessageController`.

What I know right now is that I can call the handle function of `ChatCron.php`  in `Kernel.php` in a specific date with:

```
$schedule->command('cron:chat')
         ->cron(' 4 5 30 3 6 ')
         ->background();
```

Comment: Cron is for repetitive tasks, if you want to send the chat message only once, use [queued jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) instead.

Comment: @N69S  I think it's doesn't count as once, maybe Someone wants to send Scheduled messages to lots of people in like 10 days or more. so it's like a repetitive tasks, am I wrong?

Comment: "in 10 days" is a **unique time**. not like "every time At 05:04 on day-of-month 30 and on Saturday in March." which is what cron "4 5 30 3 6" means,  which will trigger **multiple times** @`2023-03-04 05:04:00`, `2023-03-11 05:04:00`, and `2023-03-18 05:04:00`, etc... [check this](https://crontab.guru/#4_5_30_3_6)